# source file links in xcode console output

Tags: xcode

A lot of dev environments have some basic parsing logic applied to the output of programs while debugging such that if a program writes to the console (as a result of an error, assert) something like:

> /Users/Foo/Project/SomeFile.m:12 - SOMETHING BAD HAPPENED HERE

the file path & line name are automatically detected as link to source, and one can click or double click on the text in question inside the console window to make the source editor jump here.

I have been trying to find out if XCode has something similar, but I haven't had much luck. Is any such functionality missing in XCode or am I just not finding the preferred text shape that it prefers?

Thanks

Comment: Usually the debugger will stop on the line and show you the source file for an assert or a crash. Are you not seeing that? Do you have a debugger selected? If so, which one?

Answer (score 1):

I just remembered "Open Quickly…". If you copy the text of the file name, then use the "Open Quickly…" function (Cmd-Shift-O by default), you can paste the filename in and press enter, and it will display the file.

Comment: Actually if you select the filename AND the number as in 'main.m:35' then your suggestion of 'Open Quickly' will go to the exact line.